# Facebook PHP SDK login issue: It works on some networks but not on others

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-login

I'm having a weird issue when trying to log in a user in my website using the facebook SDK. Im some networks, it always works with no problems, and in others the login fails completely, even if using the same user that worked before.

Seems to be consistent across different browsers and PCs, as long as they're in the same network. From where I am right now, I can log in using the wifi connection, but not my cellphone 3G connection.

Here's a code sample. First, login page redirects to the facebook login

```
require_once("facebook/src/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
));
$loginUrl =$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(  
    'scope'        => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday',
    'redirect_uri' => "http://www.websitelink.com/app/loginCompleta.php"
    ));
//}

 header("Location: " . $loginUrl);
```

and the relevant code in the loginCompleta.php file is

```
 require_once("facebook/src/facebook.php");

 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

print_r($user);
```

And that's it. On some networks, $user will have the facebook user's id, and in others the process fails and $user returns 0. No changes in the code whatsoever, using the same facebook login.